# Instagram API redirect URL in Angular 7 application using useHash: true on Apache Server

Tags: angular, apache, url, instagram-api, angular7

How to setup Angular Application on Apache Server?

Right now I'm facing an issue on Instagram authentication.

In an Angular app, if we want to give direct access to any angular page on Apache server, let say `http://example.com/some-route`, 
then we have to enable 'useHash: true' in app.routing.
Then, it will redirect me to that route as `http://example.com/#/some-route`.

But during Instagram Authentication, IG doesn't take `#` in redirect URL.
Now when I'm passing IG redirect URL as `http://example.com/#/`, it by default returns the authentication params as `http://example.com/?code=<some-code>`, 
and before the application is able to catch the params in URL, Angular converts it to: `http://example.com/#/`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Angular. Angular CLI Angular version 7

Comment: :sir can you tell me which tutorial you to follow for implement instagram?

Comment: @Kapilsoni I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/aviabird/getting-started-with-instagram-api-integration-8c4cdd501dd4 
Also, login with Instagram is deprecated now. So I guess, this will not help you. You need to check Facebook/Instagram GraphAPI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Comment: @Faizen- actually sir I checked above but for call above API I need to generate client I'd but in my Instagram developer ther is no option showing for generate client I'd.can you help me regarding this issue?

Comment: @Kapilsoni as of June 2020, the Instagram Legacy API is disabled Check here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/. 
Please check Facebook GraphAPI. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Comment: @Faizen:thanks for valuable information sir but i am not able to generate the Client id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me: [Deploying prod build to Apache 2](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2)

I created .htaccess file with this rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase / 
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And, now I can redirect to any component without `#`. I set `useHash: false` in app router. Now, I'm able to catch the URL parameter after Instagram auth.